# Task 'gradle' not found in root project 'PreScrap' and its subprojects. Some candidates are: 'bundle'

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build, build.gradle

When I am running GRADLE SIGNINGREPORT in android studio for SHA-1 KEY then was facing that error
show how can Resolve that error

"Task 'gradle' not found in root project 'PreScrap' and its subprojects. Some candidates are: 'bundle'."

I think that problem occur due to because i switch my another laptop this project may be